# Not able to read the return values

Tags: javascript

Below code is not reading the return value from readXML() in the function matchValue(). Gives error in the line Log.Message(myarr[1,1]);

```
function readXML()
{
    var myarr;  
    var doc = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
    doc.load("C:\\Users\\sumit\\Desktop\\sfsd.xml");
    var Nodes = doc.selectNodes("//config");

    for (i = 0; i < Nodes.length; i++){
        var ChildNodes = Nodes.item(i);

        myarr = new Array();
        myarr[i,i] = [Nodes(i).childNodes(0).text, Nodes(i).childNodes(1).text];
        Log.Message(myarr[i,i]);

    } 
    return myarr;
}

function matchValue()
{
 readXML();
 Log.Message(myarr[1,1]);
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to *recreate* the array every iteration? And JavaScript doesn't have true multi-dimensional arrays, you need to have an array of arrays for that. And you *discard* what the function returns anyway.

Comment: By the way, when posting question asking about code that gives you errors, actually saying *what* those errors are is a very good idea. Please edit your question to show the actual (complete and unedited) error is.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access variables from `readXML()` in `matchValue()`. Because the variable does not exist in `matchValue()` `myarr[1,1]` gives an error.

Try storing the return value in a variable like this:

```
var array = readXML();
Log.Message(array[1,1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the result of `readXML()` when calling `matchValue()`

Save it in another variable to be able to use the result

`var result = readXML()`

Comment: @humble.rumble Yes it does since `myarr` is in the `readXML()` scope by the looks of it

Comment: @humble.rumble It's the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

## You have two main issues in your code.

## 1. Scope

If you want to access `myarr` the way you do

```
Log.Message(myarr[1,1]);
```

you have to declare it in the global namespace (which is **not** recommendable at all, and absolutely not necessary).

Instead, go like this:

```
function matchValue() {
    Log.Message(readXML()[1,1]);
}
```

### 2. Syntax to access your multidimensional array

But even though this fixes the *scope* problem, your syntax to access `myarr` is wrong. To achieve what you want, you will have to create an *outer* array whose members are also arrays. That way you can access "D" in this example in the following way:

```
var myarr = [ "A", [ "B", "C" ], [ "D", "E" ] ];
console.log(myarr[2][0]);
```

What happens at `myarr[2][0]`?

1. `myarr[2]` accesses the *outer* array and returns `["D", "E"]`.
2. Then, `["D", "E"][0]` accesses the first array member in the *inner* array.

Comment: Hi connexo , It is not printing anything. It is not giving error but blank is getting printed

Answer (score 0):

Here `myarr` is `readXML()` method local variable. So you cant access from outside.

You can do like below

```
var array = readXML();
Log.Message(array[1,1]);
```

(or) Other alternative (NOT RECOMMENDED):

make `myarray` as global variable, and access it in `matchValue()` method.

> If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.